# How to find the next element which has an ID attribute using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, siblings

When I click on a link, I need to find the next `<section>` that has an ID attribute and return its ID.

So given the following markup and javascript, I would expect clicking on the link to write "section_3" to the console.

```
<section id="section_1">
    <a href="#" class="findNext">Find</a>
</section>
<section></section>
<section id="section_3"></section>
<section id="section_4"></section>
```

and

```
$('a.findNext').click(function() {
    var nextSectionWithId = $(this).closest("section").next("section[id]");
    if (nextSectionWithId) {
        var sectionId = nextSectionWithId.attr('id');
        console.log(sectionId)
    }
});
```

But this doesn't work. I have set [the code up here in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J2ZJ9/1/).

Any ideas why this is not working?

Comment: .next doesn't search through all following siblings, it only look at the immediate next one. it's in the api docs.

Comment: If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector. Your next section doesn't have an id.

Comment: Excellent, I obviously misinterpreted it to mean "the next one to match the criteria" not "the next if it meets the criteria".

Comment: @Digbyswift: You're not the first, by far, to have made that assumption.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try :

```
var nextSectionWithId = $(this).closest("section").nextAll("section[id]:first");
```

or

```
var nextSectionWithId = $(this).closest("section").nextAll("section[id]").filter(':first');
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bR8ZH/)**

You cannot use next because next will look for a match only in the next element. So you can instead use **[nextAll](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/)** combined with [:first](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) in the selector.

**Update**

You can use the [first()](http://api.jquery.com/first/) method in jquery to fetch the first element in the collection as well which seems like a faster option.

```
var nextSectionWithId = $(this).closest("section").nextAll("section[id]").first();
```

Probably could be this reason:

> Because :first is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :first cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method. To achieve the best performance when using :first to select elements, first select the elements using a pure CSS selector, then use .filter(":first").

*Coutesy @T.J. Crowder*

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, You found it? Isn't that your question :) Good to know!!

Comment: @Liam: Yes, it is. :-) I meant "I found" as in "I learned" (in this case, from Nick [and experimentation]).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yeah probably let me add that as well... in the answer... :) Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

Use [.nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/)

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/J2ZJ9/7/)

```
var nextSectionWithId = $(this).closest("section").nextAll("section[id]")[0].id;
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/J2ZJ9/10/)

```
var nextSectionWithId = $(this).closest("section").nextAll("section[id]").eq(0).attr('id');
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/J2ZJ9/5/)

```
var nextSectionWithId = $(this).closest("section").nextAll("section[id]").attr('id');
```

Comment: I did not downvote, but reason could be that OP wants to find only the next element with the condition, not all of them. `attr('id')` works because it considers only the first element in the collection.

Comment: nextAll returns a list not an individual element. You also need the :first selector

Comment: That's better :) That said, it did seem to work, but the updated answer makes more sense.

Comment: Of course, the updated answer will throw an exception if there aren't any following siblings with `id`s, whereas `.nextAll("section[id]").attr("id")` will return the `id` of the first such sibling (if any) or `undefined` if none, rather than throwing. It's one of the few use-cases where using `.attr("id")` can actually make sense (unlike the common horror `$(this).attr("id")` one sees far too often :-) ).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Check the updated the answer used `.eq(0)` . Ty for telling me that :)

Comment: @TusharGupta: There's zero reason to use `.eq(0)` if you're using `attr` as a getter. When `attr` (or `prop`, or `css`, or `text`, or `html`, ...) is used as a *getter*, it always looks only at the first element in the set. I don't know what the answer originally looked like, but if someone downvoted it for doing `.nextAll(...).attr("id")`, that was their bad, not yours.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder hahhah my 1st answer was that only but i got Down-vote on that .

Comment: @TusharGupta: But note that the OP didn't say they wanted the *value* of the `id`. They said they wanted to find the *section* (to me that means the element, not the `id` value). So `.nextAll("section[id]").first()` or `.nextAll("section[id]:first')` as in PSL's answer.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes Sir . :)